# What CSS/Script is stopping "bgiframe" from working in IE6 on this page?

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, bgiframe

Does anyone have the expertise to quickly figure out why jquery bgiframe's plugin is not working on this page? The code is basically the exact code from the dialog plugin demo page.

http://webdev.peelregion.ca/health/destinationparenthood/template.htm

Our site template seems to not play well and I am trying to determine what exactly is causing the incompatibility.

Comment: http://webdev.peelregion.ca/health/destinationparenthood/template.htm is a more stripped down version of the page that still does not seem to work.

Comment: Site is no longer valid. Please update if still having the problem.